# WordPress reputation plug-in

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation, wordpress-se

I have formed a new limited company and on our web site there is a blog where we would like to show all the questions/answers posted by our team on Stack Overflow.

The website is based on WordPress. I know there is a plug in that allows to show the reputation along with the Q&A, but it is only for one user.

We need a plug in which can show the Q&A of multiple users. Let's say we got three developers who use to post on Stack Overflow we would like to add a section on our website to show all their posts on Stack Overflow. Is that achievable?

Comment: So, the whole system should be changed to accommodate your company?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: This is achievable, but will need some effort. You'd have to parse the users' streams using the API, maybe do some caching, and output the results.

Comment: @Oded I was asking for a plug in or kind of code snippet to acheive that I was not asking to change stackoverlflow engine to accomodate my company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for such a plugin at

http://stackapps.com

Which also has links to the API documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There is [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/3237/stacktack-wordpress-plugin-embed-stack-exchange-questions-in-your-blog), which must be added to each post manually. It adds a button to the editing toolbar that guides you through the process of embedding a question in your article.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the plugin.